# My GPIO.event_detected code is unreliable

Tags: gpio, python, rpi.gpio

I made this short program to understand `GPIO.event_detected()` better, and ended up more confused than I started. Please help me understand my mistakes. Here is the code, and some test output of me clicking the button a bunch of times:

#### code

```py
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

btn_pin = 4
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(btn_pin, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)
GPIO.add_event_detect(btn_pin, GPIO.BOTH)

def gpio_rising_event(btn_pin):
    if GPIO.event_detected(btn_pin) and GPIO.input(btn_pin) == GPIO.HIGH:
        return True
    else:
        return False


def gpio_falling_event(btn_pin):
    if GPIO.event_detected(btn_pin) and GPIO.input(btn_pin) == GPIO.LOW:
        return True
    else:
        return False


if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        while(True):
            if GPIO.event_detected(btn_pin):
                print("\nevent detected:")
            if GPIO.event_detected(btn_pin) and GPIO.input(btn_pin) == GPIO.HIGH:
                print("  rising detected in verbose way")
            if GPIO.event_detected(btn_pin) and GPIO.input(btn_pin) == GPIO.LOW:
                print("  falling detected in verbose way")
            if gpio_rising_event(btn_pin):
                print("  rising detected in concise way")
            if gpio_falling_event(btn_pin):
                print("  falling detected in concise way")
    finally:
        GPIO.cleanup()
```

#### output

```py
  rising detected in concise way
  falling detected in verbose way
  rising detected in verbose way

event detected:
  falling detected in verbose way
  rising detected in concise way

event detected:

event detected:
  falling detected in concise way
  rising detected in verbose way
  rising detected in verbose way

event detected:

event detected:
  falling detected in concise way

event detected:
  rising detected in verbose way
  rising detected in verbose way
  falling detected in concise way
  falling detected in concise way

event detected:
  falling detected in concise way

event detected:
  falling detected in verbose way
  rising detected in concise way
```

Comment: Have a read on switch bounce and removal of using hardware and / or software e.g. https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/118349/what-is-the-proper-way-to-debounce-a-gpio-input or https://www.dummies.com/computers/raspberry-pi/recognizing-and-coping-with-contact-bounce-on-the-raspberry-pi/  Voting to close as this is not a Pi issue - it's hardware...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading the state of a pin shortly AFTER an event is unreliable, particularly if you read the state multiple times.

The fundamental cause is contact bounce.
It is possible to program this in RPi.GPIO, but why reinvent the wheel when there is a library which hides all this behind a class.

See https://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api_input.html?highlight=Button#gpiozero.Button particularly Button.when_pressed and  Button.when_released

If you really want to program this in RPi.GPIO use separate event_detect for rising & falling.

```
GPIO.add_event_detect(btn_pin, GPIO.RISING, callback=gpio_rising_event)
GPIO.add_event_detect(btn_pin, GPIO.FALLING, callback=gpio_falling_event)
```

Comment: Your suggestion about having two event_detects doesn't work (says `GPIO.add_event_detect(btn_pin, GPIO.FALLING, callback=gpio_falling_event) RuntimeError: Conflicting edge detection already enabled for this GPIO channel`), but I accepted this answer because the gpiozero library accomplishes my goals while saving me the headache of coding a solution myself.

Comment: @DrakeP I admit I have not tried two event_detects, but this was copied from  https://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/migrating_from_rpigpio.html

Answer (score 1):

If it is ***contact bounce*** that's causing the problem (and it does look that way from the verbiage), there is a very simple hardware fix. If a simple & effective hardware solution interests you, [please see this answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/118367/83790).

If that doesn't interest you - then by all means, write some more code. :)

Answer (score 0):

As said it's likely to be contact bounce.

You need to be able to see all the edges to understand what is happening.

I suggest you use a library which reports the edge level in the callback.

E.g. (my) pigpio [monitor.py](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/examples.html#Python_monitor_py) or (my) lgpio [monitor.py](http://abyz.me.uk/lg/examples.html#py_lgpio%7Emonitor.py).

Another tool you will find useful is [piscope](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/piscope.html) which will show GPIO level changes in "real-time".