# Message printed multiple times when pressing hard button with RaspBerry Pi

Tags: raspbian, hardware, c, printing

I'm trying to print a message every time a button is pressed, and so far it's working fine, but the message is printed several times (somewhere around 4000 times) and I'd like it to be printed only once.

How can I fix this? I've tried several forms of validation that worked in parts, however, when I use them, the software ends or exits in the loop.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wiringPi.h>
int main(){
    wiringPiSetup();
    pinMode(25, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(3, INPUT);
    
    int pressed =0;
while (1){
    
    
    if(digitalRead(3)==1){
            //printf("pressed");
            pressed++;
            printf("RESULT  %d \n",pressed);
        }
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: google `switch debounce`

Comment: `I've tried several forms of validation` ... please add the details to your post

Comment: This is a how do I learn to program question.

Comment: The reason it happens so many times is because you are **busy looping**.  Don't do that.  Throw a 50-100ms pause into the loop. That won't deal with the **debouncing** issue but it will get you a step closer.

Comment: **"Contact Bounce"** could easily be responsible for the issue you're seeing. A [previous Q&A](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/118367/83790) here described both hardware and software solutions. If you try one of these solutions, and it doesn't work, please edit your question to include that. This is almost definitely ***fix-able.***

Comment: This question is off topic, but any attempt to use wiringPi is futile as it was deprecated 2 years ago - it is not in Bullseye.

Comment: "..software ends or exits in the loop.." FYI this has nothing to do with debouncing since you are not checking for depressed yet (you will run into this problem later). The printf function is simply called too many times in a short amount of time (your CPU is fast). When you press the button digitalRead will eventually give you 1 as long as you keep it pressed and the output buffer fills up and stdout cannot keep up with it. WiringPi (which is perfectly fine if you like it) offers a delay function. So as a first step you should add "delay(200);" at the end of the while loop.