# Button working on and off

Tags: gpio

I have two buttons connected to pins 16 and 20. The one going to pin 20 works well, actually too well. Sometimes when I press it, it records the press two times. The other button which is connected to pin 16 sometimes works and sometimes doesn't. I checked the wiring and connections and that's not it. I have a script that helps me check functionality, and the button is literally just not getting registered every other press or so. Sometimes I can press it 5 times in a row and it will see it, and then I click and click and nothing for 3-4 seconds.

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

GPIO.setup(16, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
GPIO.setup(20, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
GPIO.setup(21, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)

def print_msg(x):
    print("Button {} was pushed!".format(x))


while True:
    input_01 = GPIO.input(16)
    input_02 = GPIO.input(20)
    input_03 = GPIO.input(21)

    if input_01 == False:
        print_msg(1)
        time.sleep(0.2)
    
    if input_02 == False:
        print_msg(2)
        time.sleep(0.2)
        
    if input_03 == False:
        print_msg(3)
        time.sleep(0.2)
```

[image]

Comment: If your objective is to write a program with unpredictable outcomes you have succeeded. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: Run [piscope](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/piscope.html).  That will show you what is happening.

Comment: I suggest you try `button.when_pressed` https://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/v1.6.2/recipes.html?highlight=when_pressed#button

Comment: Milliways, why unpredictable outcomes? This script is just simply to test the button functionality.

Comment: Ok, thank you for suggestions. I used the button.when pressed and it's completely unresponsive. Thank you!

Comment: Maybe you need some kind of debouncing. You can do that with software (see for example https://docs.arduino.cc/built-in-examples/digital/Debounce) or, maybe, with a bit of hardware (just a capacitor and a resistor will help, see https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/118349/what-is-the-proper-way-to-debounce-a-gpio-input)

Comment: The fundamental problem is that you are reading switch states every microsecond or so. Normal human reaction time is ~200mS so reading more frequently is futile. These switches are notorious for bouncing so will produce dozens of transactions each press and release. Trying to read multiple inputs in a tight loop (apart from being inefficient) is unreliable. If you want to use RPi.GPIO you need to explicitly program for these. Gpiozero can do this and only detect transitions.

Comment: Recording multiple transitions when pressing the button might be the result of bouncing. Recording no button press might result from a faulty switch. You could add a LED and resistor to see if the switch actually connects the pins.

Comment: you could add a bit of sleep time in  your main loop.  as written there is only sleep if a button is pulled low.  To simplify things, change the code to just do one button and build up from there.  I cannot see anything totally wrong with what you have done other than de-bounce as others have suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, the good old days of "*It's a hardware problem ... No it's a software problem!*" Often correct software logic bumps up against the reality of physical limitations and side effects. What to do ... what to do?

**Pullup Resistors**

Pullup resistors are to force the switch logic to a known state (True|False) but the reality is that it **speeds-the-return** to minimize the *floating* or ***Maybe*** state, it does not eliminate it.

Your sleep delays are tied to your detection and print. Nothing wrong with the logic in principle but you are re-reading the switch states very very fast and the state transitions are not instantaneous, there is a ***Maybe***. What's more, *reading* does affect the output somewhat; hopefully an insignificant amount but repeated high speed pounding might make a difference. As a first step, pull your three *sleeps* out of the conditionals and put one after the last switch read to slow down your re-reads.

You are invoking the RaspberryPi programmable pullup resistors with *pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP*. This is an internal pullup resistor of around 50K ohms. As a second step, it might be beneficial to put a physical 20K pullup on the breadboard between the switch and 3.3V power. This will reduce the *maybe* time a bit and eliminate questions as to the RPi internal pullup logic.

A third step might be to hold a past *read* (*red*) state. If the intent is discrete button presses, don't process a new *read* (*reed*) if the state is the same as previously *read* (*red*). Conversely, don't process a new state unless you read it *twice* (*3?*) in a row. If the intent is to handle press duration, require *n* (*2?*) new states to acknowledge *end*.

Good Luck and let us know how you make out!